# Magento 2 disable column in order grid if order have certain status

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, uicomponent, order-grid

I want to **remove** Column **Action** from **orders grid** if order have **certain status**, how can I accomplish such behavior?

[image]

Or if it will be easier I would be happy if I could delete this **View hyperlink** :)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the **View** action for a particular order status using a plugin.

Create following files

> app/code/Venodr/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction">
        <plugin name="order_grid_view_action" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Order\Grid\ViewAction" />
    </type>

</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Order/Grid/ViewAction.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Order\Grid;

class ViewAction
{
    public function afterPrepareDataSource(
        \Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction $subject,
        $result,
        array $dataSource
    ) {
        foreach ($result['data']['items'] as & $item) {

            // add your condition here
            if ($item['status'] != 'pending') { 
                $item['actions'] = null;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Happy learning :)